# How to print integer values while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

While debugging an iOS application, I know how to print values of objects using :

**print** "variable name"
**po**    "variable name"

I wanted to know how to print values of variables which are not object-type, like for example NSInteger, int, float etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use `p intVar` to print variables.

Sometimes you need to cast: `p (CGRect)[[self view] frame]`

Comment: This is, indeed, the right solution. Also note that GDB has a `printf` function built-in too.